# Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS when using the HTTP(S) Load Balancer on Google Compute Engine

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I have HTTP/HTTPS Load Balancing set up on Google Compute Engine with 2 Global Forwarding Rules (HTTP and HTTPS). Each rule points to a back-end service with a protocol of HTTP.

I want all requests to `http://*` to go to `https://*`.

As the load balancer talks to the back-end services over HTTP I don't think I can get nginx on the back-end service to send back a `301`.

I've tried a dozen small tweaks on google compute and they all end up with google compute returning a `502`.

I'm sure somebody else has set this up before. Any tips or pointers in the right direction are much appreciated.

Comment: HTTP to HTTPS redirection (using SSL) is currently not supported through HTTP/HTTPS load balancer. The redirection needs to be configured on your web server (apache, nginx etc). With that said, please don't hesitate to file a feature request for this on the Compute Engine public issue tracker (https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/list).

Comment: Thank you; opened an issue: https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=255&thanks=255&ts=1446612833

Comment: Ok perfect, I have forwarded the feature request to engineering.

Comment: @Faizan - is there a timeline when this feature will be available? It's been around 2 years since the feature was requested. The workaround is clunky.

Comment: The new link for this request is https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904733 (though the old one still redirects).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We have a similar setup using the HTTP / HTTPS load balancer and we managed to force HTTPS. Its not possible directly from the load balancer but you can set it up from your backend service.
The Google Cloud load balancer will set the X-Forwarded-Proto http header with either the value http or https. You check this header in your backend service (in our case Varnish but this could also be done in Nginx) and if the value is http then you send back a 301.

Comment: Thanks! For the sake of posterity:

`if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {`
    `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;`
`}`

Comment: You should use HTTP `426` upgrade header rather than 301. Read More: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873247/is-http-status-code-426-upgrade-required-only-meant-signal-an-upgrade-to-a-secur

Comment: I disagree Vikram, you must use a 301 for SEO purposes. If you return a 4xx family code your pagerank will not flow across from links pointing to the old http over to https. 301 is the expected code, at least if you care about SEO on your site.

Comment: @VikramTiwari, the post answer actually states: "It's not even about upgrading from http:// to https:// at all"

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you can do it directly from HTTP(S) Load Balancing. Google Cloud released Rewrites and Redirects support (since April 2020).

See this article to learn how to setup:

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-traffic-management#console More details about this feature:

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/features#routing_and_traffic_management

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem today and was able to resolve it using TCP load balancing. If you do not need the HTTP/HTTPS specific load balancer options, perhaps you can use the TCP Load balancer (no SSL) to receive traffic to both port 80 and 443. For traffic from port 80, you can send back 301.

Comment: tcp load balancing is not permitted for port 80 [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/tcp-ssl/tcp-proxy)

> TCP Proxy Load Balancing supports the following ports: 25, 43, 110, 143, 195, 443, 465, 587, 700, 993, 995, 1883, 5222