# How can you redirect HTTP to HTTPS (GCP Load Balancing)?

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

I'm playing with GCP Load Balancing and want to redirect HTTP to HTTPS links. But cannot figure out.

My Load Balancing looks like:

```
Load balancer name
Front End:
  Protocols     IP             Certificate
  HTTP          x.x.x.x:80     -
  HTTPS         x.x.x.x:443    example-com

Back End: 
  Hosts          Paths        Backend
  example.com    /*           webs-backend
```

My webs backend is a simple nginx web server that listens on TCP/80 port. Nginx server configs:

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  root /var/www/html;

  <snip>
}
```

Now with this GCP Load Balancing setup, I can access both HTTP and HTTPS, tried to configure Nginx to send cleints 301 redirect to HTTPS and it won't work. Too many redirects.

Question is, how can I configure GCP Load Balancing to redirect HTTP to HTTPS properly?

Comment: possible duplicate - https://serverfault.com/questions/733166/redirect-all-http-traffic-to-https-when-using-the-https-load-balancer-on-googl

Answer (score 6):

There is feature request submitted to Google product engineering team to support it on GCP HTTP(s) load-balancer. You can track this on Google public issue [tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/35904733).

There is a [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/733166/redirect-all-http-traffic-to-https-when-using-the-https-load-balancer-on-googl) discussing the same and in NGINX server you can accomplish the same by adding following string into nginx configuration file like this:

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") { 
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 
}
```

You can check this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/250476/how-to-force-or-redirect-to-ssl-in-nginx) as well which may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can do it directly from HTTP(S) Load Balancing. Google Cloud released Rewrites and Redirects support (since April 2020).

See this article to learn how to setup:

- https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-traffic-management#console

More details about this feature:

- https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/features#routing_and_traffic_management